# Homepage to serve the content of page created from a plugin

Tags: plugins

**NOTE:** This is a duplicate issue since I have posted it to a [wrong channel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/374984/homepage-to-serve-content-from-my-custom-landing-page). I just figured out this community of wordpress here in SO.

I am new to wordpress and trying to achieve something.

I have a landing page created from a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-link-pages/) and I want my homepage to serve the content of that landing page without any redirection.

E.g. `site.com` should read the content of my `site.com/landing_page`

Is there any way to do it programmatically? Or via dashboard?

The code below does not satisfy my condition since the homepage is redirected to the landing page itself.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'default_page');
function default_page(){
    if(is_home() or is_front_page()){
       exit( wp_redirect("site.com/landing_page"));
    }
}
```

I also raise this concern to the [plugin page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/homepage-to-serve-the-content-of-social-link/).

TIA

Comment: This is still off-topic, because it's a plugin specific question that can only be answered by the plugin support.

Comment: ok, anyway thanks!

Comment: I am actually more interested if there's a way to do it programatically.